# Metrics around Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there a way we can find some metrics around batching. For eg. How many bytes of data are being transmitted on every batch and at what time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka provides you a method called `metrics()` in the `KafkaProducer`.

You can get the metrics as a map.You can find more info below.

https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#metrics()